# Homebrew don't work after upgrading to macOS11

Tags: macos, homebrew

After upgrading to macOS11, my Homebrew don't work.

With `brew update`, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:21:in `<module:OS>'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:58:in `prerelease?'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `version'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `new'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:23:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:368:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it with the help of this [blog](https://saschaeggi.medium.com/fix-homebrew-brew-on-macos-11-big-sur-14862a4d5fab).

1. Remove old xcode command line tools

   `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
2. Install new xcode command line tools

   `sudo xcode-select --install`
3. Update brew (Attention: you may need to run it twice)

   `brew upgrade`
4. If you still get an error message try to reinstall brew via:

   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
5. Test if brew works

Comment: The first 3 steps don't work for me and later I tried step 4, got "curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused". However, luckily I found another way at https://www.cnblogs.com/liyihua/p/12753163.html